# AccountController doesn't seem to work with fluent nhibernate and StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, structuremap

In my account controller i am trying to get an object of nhibernate ISession but on CreateContoller method of my controller factory class StructureMapControllerFactory it throws "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.". Although with any other controller it works fine.

Below is my StructureMapControllerFactory class:

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
        public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            try
            {
                var controllerType = base.GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);
                return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Use the default logic
                return base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
            }
        }
}
```

and code snippet from Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new SmartHRMS.Utility.StructureMapControllerFactory());
            StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                {
                    x.For<NHibernate.ISessionFactory>()
                        .Singleton()
                        .Use(SmartHRMS.Utility.SessionHelper.GetSessionFactory());

                    x.For<NHibernate.ISession>()
                        .HttpContextScoped()
                        .Use(context => context.GetInstance<NHibernate.ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());
                });

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {
            StructureMap.ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
        }
```

Exception:

```
{"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'HCM.Controllers.AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."}
```

Comment: The exception message you posted is from `DefaultControllerFactory` trying to instantiate your controller. Try and remove the `try-catch` stuff around your call to StructureMap to see what the real problem is.

Comment: yes it did the trick, i posted an answer to show how i solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mookid8000 who gave me the hint, after finding out the actual error i changed my StructureMapControllerFactory and Global.asax.cs like this:

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        readonly Container container;

        public StructureMapControllerFactory(Container container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
                return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            try
            {
                return container.GetInstance(controllerType) as Controller;
            }
            catch (StructureMapException)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
```

and

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            var container = new StructureMap.Container(config =>
                {                    
                    config.For<System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider>()
                        .Use(System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider);

                    config.For<SmartHRMSTest.Controllers.IFormsAuthentication>()
                        .Use<SmartHRMSTest.Controllers.FormsAuthenticationService>();

                    config.For<SmartHRMSTest.Controllers.IMembershipService>()
                        .Use<SmartHRMSTest.Controllers.AccountMembershipService>();

                    config.For<NHibernate.ISessionFactory>()
                        .Singleton()
                        .Use(SmartHRMS.Utility.SessionHelper.GetSessionFactory());

                    config.For<NHibernate.ISession>()
                        .HttpContextScoped()
                        .Use(context => context.GetInstance<NHibernate.ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());
                });

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new SmartHRMS.Utility.StructureMapControllerFactory(container));

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```